# CustomAccount deserialization issue

Tags: solana-program, rust, program

I have this piece of code, it skips the first 8 bytes of the account data as that's the descriminator

```
pub struct CustomProgramAccountStruct {
    pub pubkey: Pubkey,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub token: Pubkey,
}

fn handle_account(
    &self,
    account_info: &AccountInfo,
) -> Result<Box<dyn ParseResult + 'static>, CustomError> {
    let account_data = if let Some(account_info) = account_info.data() {
        account_info.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()
    } else {
        return Err(CustomError::DeserializationError);
    };

    let account_type = match account_data.len() {
        300 => {
            let account: CustomProgramAccountStruct = try_from_slice_unchecked(&account_data[8..])?;
            CustomProgramAccount::Account(account)
        }
        _ => {
            return Err(CustomError::InvalidDataLength);
        }
    };

    Ok(Box::new(account_type))
}
```

But the problem is when I check the saved data in database, I see `token` is saved in `authority` column and `token` column has an public key entirely different. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

The `pubkey` property in the struct was causing the issue. The account data doesn't have that property.